# Does Windows update KB3033929 modify the boot loader making it difficult to install on a dual boot system?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-update, boot-camp

We have been unable to install Windows update KB3033929 on a MacBook Pro with Bootcamp either directly booted to Windows or running Windows as a VM with VMware Fusion.

There appears to be a known issue with dual-boot systems although Microsoft only mentions system that dual-boot Linux.

Can this update safely be hidden in this case or is there a way to get it installed?

Comment: This seems fairly straight forward: "We have been able to verify that systems that have the Windows boot loader enabled as the primary loader are successfully able to install this update and that systems that have a non-Windows boot loader specified as the primary boot loader cannot install the update, even if the user uses that loader to select Windows."

Answer (score 1):

From a [security advisory](https://www.its.ny.gov/security-advisory/microsoft-security-advisory-3033929-causing-issues-windows-7):
We recommend the following actions be taken:
Do not apply Microsoft Update 3033929 until this issue has been corrected, or a supported work around is available.

There are also [posts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb3033929-fails-to-install-and-cause-a-minor/4c56d5d5-a66c-4865-8ccb-d36f7c314c33) at Microsoft community forum indicating that this is not exclusive to dual-boot.